# how do I check different sample backgrounds with firebug?

Tags: css, firebug

I am looking at a website. Say it's any website. I'd like to see what one of them looks like with this gif image I have on my desktop. Is there a way to check? It's not like changing the background color, rather I need to give a filepath to my own desktop. (I have tried just punching int he filepath)
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just save the page and try out with your background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to host your image online (at dropbox, for example) and then get the public link for that image. In firebug alter the body tag. For this page, the code would look like this:

```
<body class="question-page" style="background: url('yoururl.jpg')">
```

To confirm you have the code working properly first, add this to the Firebug code:

```
<body class="question-page" style="background-color: pink">
```

and the background will become pink.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.

You can upload the images to a site like [imgur](http://imgur.com) and just link there instead.

Or save the webpage locally and modify it.